# Asymptotic Complexity comparison

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

**Can anybody explain which one of them has highest asymptotic complexity and why,**

```
10000000n vs 1.000001^n vs n^2
```

Comment: Yes.  But because this is your homework, you should be able to figure it out.

Comment: You can add your try and your reasonment, then we can help you in one point. Maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use standard domination rules from [asymptotic analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Domination rules tell you that when `n -> +Inf`, `n = o(n^2)`. (Note the difference between the notations `O(.)` and `o(.)`, the latter meaning `f(n) = o(g(n))` iff there exists a sequence `e(n)` which converges to `0` as `n -> +Inf` such that `f(n) = e(n)g(n)`. With `f(n) = n`, `g(n) = n^2`, you can see that `f(n)/g(n) = 1/n -> 0` as `n -> +Inf`.)

Furthermore, you know that for any integer `k` and real `x > 1`, we have `n^k/x^n -> 0` as `n -> +Inf`. `x^n` (exponential) complexity dominates `n^k` (polynomial) complexity.

Therefore, in order of increasing complexity, you have:

```
n << n^2 << 1.000001^n
```

Note:`10000000n` could be written `O(n)` with the *loose* written conventions used for asymptotic analysis in computer science. Recall that the complexity `C(n)` of an algorithm is `O(n)` (`C(n) = O(n)`) if and only if (iff) there exists an integer `p >= 0` and `K >= 0` such that for all `n >= p` the relation `|C(n)| <= K.n` holds.

Answer (score 0):

When calculating asymptotic time complexity, you need to ignore all coefficients of `n` and just focus on its exponent.

The higher the exponent, the higher the time complexity.

**In this case**

We ignore the coefficients of `n`, leaving `n^2, x^n and n`.

However, we ignore the second one as it has an exponent  of `n`. As `n^2` is higher than `n`, the answer to your question is `n^2`.